# Updating nextcloud docker container on RPI

Tags: docker, nextcloud

I am running nextcloud in a docker container on my Raspberry Pi. I have set it up witih self-signed certificates as described [here](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/howto-running-nextcloud-over-self-signed-https-ssl-tls-in-docker/101973). These are my files to run the docker-compose:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nextcloud:apache
COPY setssl.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN /usr/local/bin/setssl.sh mail@mail.com 172.30.0.2
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '2'

services:
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud_ssl
    build: .
    container_name: nextcloud
    restart: always
    user: 1000:1000
    ports:
      - 8443:443
    volumes:
      - /home/pi/nextcloud/ncdata:/var/www/html
      - /home/pi/nextcloud/ssl:/etc/ssl/nextcloud
      - /home/pi/pictures:/var/www/html/data/files/pics
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zzz-custom.ini
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=xxx
      - MYSQL_USER=xxx
      - MYSQL_HOST=xxx
      - MYSQL_PORT=xxx

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: mariabridge
```

setssl.sh

```
# setssl.sh
# USAGE: setssl.sh <email> <domain>

echo 'SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains"
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
SSLCompression off
SSLSessionTickets Off' > /etc/apache2/conf-available/ssl-params.conf
echo "<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin $2
                ServerName $1
" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
echo '
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/nextcloud/cert.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/nextcloud/key.pem

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>' >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
a2enmod ssl >/dev/null
a2ensite default-ssl >/dev/null
a2enconf ssl-params >/dev/null
```

According to the linked thread above, I have to run these commands to update my container:

```
docker-compose build --pull
docker-compose up -d
```

I have used this successfully before. Now, I'm getting the following errors:

```
docker-compose build --pull
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/
Building nextcloud
Sending build context to Docker daemon  45.65GB

Step 1/3 : FROM nextcloud:apache
apache: Pulling from library/nextcloud
Digest: sha256:99d94124b2024c9f7f38dc12144a92bc0d68d110bcfd374169ebb7e8df0adf8e
Status: Image is up to date for nextcloud:apache
 ---> 0dd24a9c32e9
Step 2/3 : COPY setssl.sh /usr/local/bin/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 360b5260b30a
Step 3/3 : RUN /usr/local/bin/setssl.sh mail@mail.com 172.30.0.2
 ---> Running in 4e77f23a45f2
touch: setting times of '/var/lib/apache2/module/enabled_by_admin/socache_shmcb': Operation not permitted
ERROR: Failed to create marker '/var/lib/apache2/module/enabled_by_admin/socache_shmcb'!
ERROR: Could not enable dependency socache_shmcb for ssl, aborting
touch: setting times of '/var/lib/apache2/site/enabled_by_admin/default-ssl': Operation not permitted
ERROR: Failed to create marker '/var/lib/apache2/site/enabled_by_admin/default-ssl'!
touch: setting times of '/var/lib/apache2/conf/enabled_by_admin/ssl-params': Operation not permitted
ERROR: Failed to create marker '/var/lib/apache2/conf/enabled_by_admin/ssl-params'!
The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/setssl.sh mail@mail.com 172.30.0.2' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'nextcloud' failed to build
```

I tried running this as sudo as well (running it as pi usually), but it didn't solve the issue. Not sure what to do here. The nextcloud forums is not really that active to ask for help..

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 3/3 : RUN /usr/local/bin/setssl.sh mail@mail.com 172.30.0.2
 ---> Running in 4e77f23a45f2
touch: setting times of '/var/lib/apache2/module/enabled_by_admin/socache_shmcb': Operation not permitted
ERROR: Failed to create marker '/var/lib/apache2/module/enabled_by_admin/socache_shmcb'!
ERROR: Could not enable dependency socache_shmcb for ssl, aborting
touch: setting times of '/var/lib/apache2/site/enabled_by_admin/default-ssl': Operation not permitted
ERROR: Failed to create marker '/var/lib/apache2/site/enabled_by_admin/default-ssl'!
touch: setting times of '/var/lib/apache2/conf/enabled_by_admin/ssl-params': Operation not permitted
ERROR: Failed to create marker '/var/lib/apache2/conf/enabled_by_admin/ssl-params'!
The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/setssl.sh mail@mail.com 172.30.0.2' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If the RUN step that's filing now used to work, it's because your upstream `nextcloud:apache` has added a USER line in the dockerfile and the USER they added does not have access to `/var/lib/apache2`.

The solution is simple, if inelegant.

1. Figure out which `USER` is set in the `nextcloud:apache` upstream image.
2. Add a `USER`  command of your own before the `CMD` that runs `setssl.sh` to set the user to one that has access to `/var/lib/apache2`
3. Add another USER command to switch back to the user from `nextcloud:apache`.

> I tried running this as sudo as well (running it as pi usually), but it didn't solve the issue.

No, `sudo` wouldn't.  This all happens in docker land, so running docker build / docker compose with sudo doesn't change any of that.

Let me share one more thought with you.  I assume you authored `setssl.sh`.  One of many idiosyncrasies of `sh` is that failed commands do not typically end the script by default, while most non-shell programming languages won't continue to run after a statement generates an error.  You should always run the shell with `-e` in the shebang line, run `set -e`, or the equivalent in non-bourn-like shells to make sure your shell command will error if its commands error, which is appropriate for this case.  (If you're curious, `setssl.sh` returns the exit code of the last `touch` command that ran, but it should have failed after the *first* command that failed!)  Otherwise your docker build will succeed but the docker image won't have the files you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've added the -e to the setssl.sh.

TBH I have no idea how to figure out the user. I will try the nextcloud forums, but I doubt anyone will help there.